# The necessity of an indefinite article: The drinking segment is estimated to hold about 44.8% volume share by the end of 2026

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

I'm not sure if an indefinite article is required in the below sentence:

> The drinking segment is estimated to hold about **a** 44% volume share by the end of 2022.
>
> The drinking segment is estimated to hold about **an** 84.8% volume share by the end of 2022.

The original sentence is given below. I stumble upon similar sentences while editing some work, but I'm never quite certain.

> The drinking segment is estimated to hold about 44.8% volume share by the end of 2026.

Comment: You have it right. Use the article that matches how you say the number: a 44% share, and an 84% share. To avoid choosing, redo the order: "to hold a volume share of 44% (or 84%)."

Comment: Well, my main question is that in the given sentence is there a need for a/an at all? "The drinking segment is estimated to hold about 44.8% volume share by the end of 2026."

Comment: For good English, use the article. For math jargon, you can skip it when all your readers are technical.